# Preparing regex for parsing simple string

Tags: java, regex

I get a simple string from which I want to extract some values. The values are separated by whitespace characters as follows:

```
abc               0.00    11.00    0.00    4.50     0.00   124.00    27.56     0.01    1.44   0.89   0.40
```

I want to get those values: abc, 0.00, 11.00,...

I tried this:

```
    String line = "abc               0.00    11.00    0.00    4.50     0.00   124.00    27.56     0.01    1.44   0.89   0.40";
    String regex = "^([\\w\\.]*)\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\$";
    Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(line); 
    if(matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(6));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(7));           
        System.out.println(matcher.group(8));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(9));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(10));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(11));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(12));          
    }
```

I am getting following output:

```
abc
0
0
0
0
0
0
6
1
4
9
0
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You really feel that you need `^([\\w\\.]*)\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\\s+([\\w\\.])*\$` just to split this string into it's parts?

Comment: You can use `String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");`

Comment: @Takendarkk yess cause I dont know what i will be getting in this regex variable. I will be getting the regex from user input file. This is somewhat related to generalizing the data extraction process.

Comment: @anubhava I know I can use string methods, but both string to be parsed and how to parse it changes time to time. So generalizing it with regex.

Comment: Lol you call that "generalizing"? Poor approach.

Comment: `So generalizing it with regex.` Your regex is the **complete opposite** of generalizing

Comment: @JonathonReinhart what else I can do?  If I use `String.split()` then user will be forced to provide the regex for splitting each line of the file. And consider if the line splitter is not same, then he will be forced to provide mutliple splitters. Though this is possible, I am following group capturing as user will at first anyway specify the regex for whole line, to indicate which all lines in a file need to be parsed. Then he only needs to specify the groups to be captured on that line, so regex will mostly be the same. What is better way to do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp is wrong. The quantity qualifier must be put inside the group delimiter, not outside, indeed the first group is ok.
This is the correct RegExp:

```
([\w\.]*)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)\s+([\w\.]+)
```

Tested on: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Now that's precisely pointed out stupid mistake in my regex: *The quantity qualifier must be put inside the group delimiter, not outside*

Comment: It happens: that regexp is quite complex. I suggest you to use the cited regexp tester, I find it very useful.

Answer (score 4):

- Firstly, your example won't compile as you have a hanging `\` at the end of the pattern `String`.
- Secondly, you misplaced the greedy 0+ quantifier in all groups following the first one - you can easily work around it by using: `([\\w\\.]*)` instead of `([\\w\\.])*`
- The subtle difference between the above patterns lies essentially in what you are grouping
- Thirdly, you're probably better of splitting your input by whitespace and iterating over the array elements

**Example**

```
String line = "abc               0.00    11.00    0.00    4.50     0.00   124.00    27.56     0.01    1.44   0.89   0.40";
String[] items = line.split("\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
```

**Output**

```
[abc, 0.00, 11.00, 0.00, 4.50, 0.00, 124.00, 27.56, 0.01, 1.44, 0.89, 0.40]
```

**Note**

As your array is (0-)indexed, you can retrieve each item by its index, e.g. `items[0]`, `items[1]`, ... `items[items.length - 1]`.

Comment: unfortunately I cant use string methods. This is more related to auto data extraction from different types of files. I dont want to write custom code for each different type of files. Thus I wrote code which takes each line of a file, matches given regex against it and captures its groups as values to be extracted. This allows more flexibility as user can specify the data file path and regex to parse that file in another config file. Now I dont have to write custom code for parsing each file but just a config file specifying the regex to be used.

Comment: @Mahesha999 but why can't you use `String` methods? Is this homework?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Your claim that `This allows more flexibility` is just flat out wrong. You are adding so much complexity for no reason.

Comment: @Takendarkk I agree with you within the context so far. By the way, the split token could always be made variable, if you have differently separated inputs (for simple cases at least).

Comment: @Mena lol no this is not homework. If I use `String.split()` then user will be forced to provide the regex for splitting each line of the file. And consider if the line splitter is not same, then he will be forced to provide mutliple splitters. Though this is possible, I am following group capturing as user will at first anyway specify the regex for whole line, to indicate which all lines in a file need to be parsed. Then he only needs to specify the groups to be captured on that line, so regex will mostly be the same.

Comment: @Mahesha999 that seems way more convoluted than providing the user with a simple token for splitting, and maybe the indices they are interested in keeping. But that's my opinion.

Comment: @Mena I am providing the code which will be doing group capturing and extracting the values, the user is told to specify the regex with group and indices of those groups in a file. My code will then capture those groups and persist them to database. ** Is there any better way to design this? **
(What I am doing now is just testing the functionality of my code. Above is just the test code, not even my original code. Just preparing regex for that particular line. I will be feeding that regex next to my actual code to test it out.)

Comment: @Mahesha999 I think so: by getting the split iterator (and optional indices required) from the user and executing the split / element collection / error handling (on non-existing indices, bad pattern, etc.) in your code :)

Comment: nope, am just asking which will be better approach: executing splits vs capturing groups vs something completely new way?   (given that the input file can be almost anything rubbish or better to say very frequently varying)

Comment: did u mean split iterator approach is better? How? With groups capturing, regex matching will be done once and then we have to just capture groups. With split, may be, regex is matched multiple times with each `split()` call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different regex only to match the digits

```
\\d+\\.\\d+
```

- `\\d+` Matches one or more digits
- `\\.` Matches a `.`

**Example**

```
String line = "abc               0.00    11.00    0.00    4.50     0.00   124.00    27.56     0.01    1.44   0.89   0.40";
String regex = "\\d+\\.\\d+";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(line); 
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}

/* Output

0.00
11.00
0.00
4.50
0.00
124.00
27.56

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to make it so complex?

Use split and then spilt it with `//s+`  one or more than one white space.

Then take it from the array.

```
String string = "sdn agsd ds     adg sd g dsg sdg  dsg dsg";
String []tokens = string.split("\\s+");
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i)
  System.out.println(tokens[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    String line = "abc               0.00    11.00    0.00    4.50     0.00   124.00    27.56     0.01    1.44   0.89   0.40";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```